# AFNetworking is legal?

Tags: app-store, afnetworking

I got response from Apple Review Team:

> Dear Developer,
>
> Your app, extension, and/or linked framework appears to contain code
>   designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior
>   or functionality after App Review approval, which is not in compliance
>   with section 3.3.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement
>   and App Store Review Guideline 2.5.2. This code, combined with a
>   remote resource, can facilitate significant changes to your app’s
>   behavior compared to when it was initially reviewed for the App Store.
>   While you may not be using this functionality currently, it has the
>   potential to load private frameworks, private methods, and enable
>   future feature changes.
>
> This includes any code which passes arbitrary parameters to dynamic
>   methods such as dlopen(), dlsym(), **respondsToSelector:**,
>   **performSelector:**, **method_exchangeImplementations()**, and running remote
>   scripts in order to change app behavior or call SPI, based on the
>   contents of the downloaded script. Even if the remote resource is not
>   intentionally malicious, it could easily be hijacked via a Man In The
>   Middle (MiTM) attack, which can pose a serious security vulnerability
>   to users of your app.
>
> Please perform an in-depth review of your app and remove any code,
>   frameworks, or SDKs that fall in line with the functionality described
>   above before submitting the next update for your app for review.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

I check my code again and I see AFNetworking included methods: **performSelector:**, **method_exchangeImplementations()**, **respondsToSelector:**

I intend to tell Apple that AFNetworking is an opensource and legal but I think Apple will NOT trust me

**So I have 2 questions:**

1. Does Apple ask me to remove AFNetworking from my code after they know AFNetworking included **respondsToSelector:**, **performSelector:**, **method_exchangeImplementations()**
2. As the way Apple see AFNetworking, is AFNetworking legal? Are there any documents to prove it?

Comment: Really interesting situation. Can you provide details about how AFNetworking is being included in your app? (Carthage, Cocoapods, etc and the respective cartfile of podfile.) Also seems weird since so much top apps on the Apps store are using it, just check this: https://mightysignal.com/top-ios-sdks?tag=4 Are there any other frameworks or libraries in your app?

Comment: I have the same issue. I was using Rollout.io which is a library that does have abilities to change the code after sending it to the AppStore. Do you have anything of that sort? I'm trying to find the common library here that causes Apple to send this to developers in the recent days.

Comment: I used JSPatch, Apple checked and rejected my app :((((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the same message and reading in different forums, it is possible you are using a 3rd party service which allows you to alter the code after uploading the app to the AppStore.
The most popular service for that is Rollout.io, which I had to remove from my own app.

I strongly doubt that AFNetworking would cause you any issues (still looking for an answer from Apple myself, and will update when they do answer)

**Update:** Apple has approved my app, meaning it was Rollout.io indeed. I believe it'll be true for any 3rd party code injection tool.
I still have AFNetworking, so no problems there.

Comment: Rollout, Apple are fighting: https://rollout.io/blog/open-letter-to-apple-secure-javascript-injection-ios/

Comment: Indeed - got an email from Rollout as well as this open letter.

Comment: Apple's support message was vague about AFNetworking (they didn't answer directly and just told me to upload a build). My build is currently in review and I'll update what will its status be.